# Interpolation using Numpy. IndexError: Index 71 is out of bound for axis 0 with size 71

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have a function that takes three arrays and runs a few lines of code to interpolate the data.
It looks something like this:

```
def interpolate(a, b, c): 
    # Avoid crashing if a > max(b)
    xm_ = b[-1]
    a[a > xm_] = xm_

    i = np.arange(a.size)
    j = np.searchsorted(b, a) - 1

    d = (a - b[j]) / (b[j + 1] - b[j])

    return (1 - d) * c[i, j] + c[i, j + 1] * d
```

Here are the shapes of the arrays:
a is (163080,)
b is (71,)
c is (162080, 71)

I keep running into the IndexError. I have tried to extend the b with higher values to try to not hit max values. I have also tried to use up to fourth last index when assigning xm_.

Any suggestions to what might be happening here? And potentially how to solve it?

Cheers!

Comment: Python is zero-based: an array with 71 elements uses indexes [0:70].

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem happens here: d = (a - b[j]) / (b[j + 1] - b[j])

    return (1 - d) * c[i, j] + c[i, j + 1] * d.  Have the loop iterate from [0:69]

Comment: @duffymo yes indeed. Error occurs when assigning d. I have tried to have the loop iterate length of the array minus a few indexes. No luck unfortunately.